# Reassigning the Workflow dynamically

Tags: workflow, office-365, workflow-activity

I would like to reassign the workflow not the task in O365 Sharepoint.

Example:

I have 5 workflows naming 1,2,3,4,5.

Item 1 to 3 has been approved. 4th person found there was an issue on 2 stage of approval. Here I want to reassign the workflow to 2 from 4. Then again the workflow has to start from 2 to 5 again.

Please let me know can I able to achieve it in O365 Sharepoint.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this as OOTB, but you can merge all workflows as asub workflow in a main workflow and each sub workflow will be added to a stage in the main workflow.

In this case, you can go to any stage that contains your workflow steps based on a specific condition.

[image]

For more details check

- [Creating a workflow by using SharePoint Designer 2013 and the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671.aspx)
- [SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow goto step basics](http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-goto-step.htm)